# Dynamically call function from another file in python while in runtime using flask

Tags: python, flask

I would like to use flask to run some functions. Assume you have a file called `myapp.py` with a function `run`

```
def run():
    return 'special routed hello world'
```

and this *main* flask file, something like this

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'hello world'

@app.route('/<myapp>')
def open_app(myapp):
    from myapp import run
    return run()
```

So obvisouly that doesn't work, but how can I dynamically call these run functions when flask is already running. Is this even possible?
In other words: when someone opens for example .../foobar, the function `open_app` with parameter `foobar` is begin called. In that function, from the file `foobar.py` (let's assume that file exists) import function `run`, run it and return the result from that function.

Comment: I have no idea what `from app import run` should be doing.

Comment: There isn't a module called `app`. You have `myapp` but if your question is inconsistent, it's tough to understand how much of this you actually understand. In any case, you can build sprawling packages that are wrapped in a flask app so all I can say is "yes, it's even possible"

Comment: so somebody calls /foobar, then the function open_app is called with parameter 'foobar'. The function shall import from the file foobar.py the function `run`, run it and return the result

Comment: You can certainly import modules dynamically with the `importlib` module, although I'm not sure that's a very good idea for a public-facing web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it is possible to use [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html), especially [`import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module)in combination with [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), to dynamically call up functions of a module. And I have security concerns too.

The following two examples show a kind of simple RPC implementation.

The first example uses a dictionary for modules. If a module with the name is available, the run function is called. It allows a strong restriction. Optimization is certainly possible and probably necessary.

The second example shows a possibility of calling different functions within different modules with parameters. In spite of everything, as with the previous version, all modules are in one package called "actions" to ensure that calls can be limited. I also think a variant with POST is more suitable for this purpose than using variable rules.

Remember these are strong simplifications. Protocols such as JSON-RPC will certainly help as a guide during implementation.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify, request, jsonify
from importlib import import_module
from actions import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'

@app.route('/exec/<string:action>', methods=['POST'])
def exec(action):
    result = cmddict[action].run()
    return jsonify(result=result)

@app.route('/call', methods=['POST'])
def call():
    data = request.get_json()
    module = data.get('module')
    method = data.get('method')
    params = data.get('params')

    try:
        # import module by name
        m = import_module(f'actions.{module}', __name__)
        # get function by name
        f = getattr(m, method)
        # call function with params
        result = f(**params) if isinstance(params, dict) else f(*params)
        return jsonify(result=result, error=None)
    except Exception as err:
        return jsonify(result=None, error=f'{err}')
```

```
# ./actions/__init__py
__all__ = ['demo']

from importlib import import_module

cmddict = {}
for _ in __all__:
    cmddict[_] = import_module(f'actions.{_}', __name__)
__all__.append('cmddict')
```

```
# ./actions/demo.py
def run():
    return f'hello world'

def func(*args, **kwargs):
    print('func', args, kwargs)
``
```